# Bootstrap alert is show at page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I tiny confused because the bootstrap alert is shown at page load in asp.net here is the code:-

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show some alert message on when some task is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a completely basic example explaining your doubt. The alert message is visible on load as you are not hiding your message in any scenario.

In the below-given code snippet, I am displaying the alert message on a button click using jQuery - [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/). On load the alert message is hidden using css - [`display: none`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-danger').click(function(){
        $('.alert').show();
    }) 
});
```

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <label>Danger!</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Show Alert</button>
</div>
```